# Tradingview widget - customize simple moving average and Exponential moving average lenght

Tags: javascript, widget, tradingview-api

I'm trying to add "Advanced Real Time chart" widget from tradinview. I'm able to add indicator Exponential moving average and Simple moving average. But it takes default 9 days length. I want to change that.

I tried as below but it does not work. Could somebody please help. Thanks a lot in advance.

```
widget = new TradingView.widget(
    {
        "width": 1200,
        "height": 700,
        "symbol": "NSE:DRREDDY",
        "interval": "D",
        "timezone": "Asia/Kolkata",
        "theme": "Dark",
        "style": "1",
        "locale": "in",
        "toolbar_bg": "#f1f3f6",
        "enable_publishing": false,
        "hide_side_toolbar": false,
        "allow_symbol_change": true,
        "details": true,
        "studies_overrides": {
            "moving average exponential.length": 20
        },
        "studies": [
            "MAExp@tv-basicstudies"
        ],

        "container_id": "tradingview_f6d89"
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide the full widget code, not only the *settings* and results vs expected output. Please remember that SO is not a code-writing service.

Answer (score 7):

Here's the way to do it :

```
"studies": [
   {
     "id": "MAExp@tv-basicstudies",
     "version": 60,
     "inputs": {
       "length": 20
     }
   },
   ...
```

Comment: Not quite sure why - but this doesn't work when I am trying to edit the widget

Comment: Thanks @Clément Letellier, do you know if it's possible to change the color too?  Is there any documentation?

Comment: where can we find the documentation to customize/override the default properties of indicators?

Comment: Thanks to @clément-letellier. Do you know, what does the line `"version": 60` mean? - I've removed the line and could not find any difference, so is the line needed? Would be also interested in a documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The code above takes EMA `20` ticks back on the current time frame (TF), so if you want days, you need to set TF to `days` and change this value to `9` (or equivalently, set TF to *hours* and set EMA to `24*9`).